# Not able to set cookie on url in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies

I have an application wherein from one of my url I am getting cookie and I am looping through the cookie array to get the cookie I need, and then on my webviewcontroller I am setting this cookie. The problem is I am able to get cookie but not able to set the cookie.I have done the code properly but don't know why the cookie is not getting set in iOS.

This is my code to get cookie:

```
NSURL* aUrl =
      [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.cookie.com/session/create"];
  NSMutableURLRequest* request =
      [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                          timeoutInterval:30.0];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
  NSError* error = nil;
  NSHTTPURLResponse* res = nil;
  NSData* returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                             returningResponse:&res
                                                         error:&error];
  NSArray* httpscookies =
      [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[res allHeaderFields]
                                             forURL:aUrl];
  for (int i = 0; i < [httpscookies count]; i++) {
    cookie = [httpscookies objectAtIndex:i];
  }

  [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]
           setCookies:httpscookies
               forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.session.com/"]
      mainDocumentURL:nil];
```

I am able to fetch the cookie array in my httpscookies var

```
(
<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"JSESSIONID" value:"03C4DB8AE44C53A9E552E1312D6F204D.pgnode1" expiresDate:(null) created:2014-06-04 06:35:11 +0000 (4.23557e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"www.session.com" path:"/" isSecure:TRUE>,
<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:”mycookie” value:”aeftfec51c4d64bb6a258d53d6ebe8f10b801e047e2d387cef3b770399c16bc1e6cc9ce5167ceab7a6d9d3af1d8351a7b07cf04129f149a" expiresDate:2015-06-04 06:38:15 +0000 created:2014-06-04 06:35:11 +0000 (4.23557e+08) sessionOnly:FALSE domain:”www.session.com” path:"/" isSecure:TRUE>
)
```

This is the code to set cookie to my web view

```
NSArray* cookies;
  NSDictionary* cookieHeaders;
  NSMutableURLRequest* request;

  cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
  if (!cookies) {
    return;
  }

  [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies:cookies
                                                     forURL:webviewurl
                                            mainDocumentURL:nil];
```

**//webviewurl is url of web view**. I need 'mycookie' value to get set on the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this is working for me.Using below code u can store cookies.

```
NSString *urlString =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.some url%@",
     [newuaernamedsde stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                    initWithRequest:request
                                    delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                          forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [connection start];


    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) 
    {
     //   NSLog(@"%@cookiecookiecookiecookie", cookie);
    }
```

Here using below code u can set cookie to my web view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:geturllink]];
        [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
        [self addCookies:cookies forRequest:request];
        [webpageeee loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)addCookies:(NSArray *)cookies forRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
    {
        if ([cookies count] > 0)
        {
            NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
            NSString *cookieHeader = nil;
            for (cookie in cookies)
            {
                if (!cookieHeader)
                {
                    cookieHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@=%@",[cookie name],[cookie value]];
                }
                else
                {
                    cookieHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@; %@=%@",cookieHeader,[cookie name],[cookie value]];
                }
            }
            if (cookieHeader)
            {
                [request setValue:cookieHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
            }
        }
    }
```